# powershell - select an object from an object array

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I import a CSV file containing a primary key and some data, for example

```
key,data
1,one
2,two
3,three
4,four
5,five
```

I want the `data` field of one record, based on the `key` value. here's what I do

```
$db=import-csv data.csv
$data=($db|?{$_.key -eq 4}).data
```

is there a smarter/more elegant way to write the second line ?

PS. for this time, I'm stuck with PS v2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more elegant way, not sure about performance though:

```
# Convert CSV to Hashtable
$db = Import-CSV data.csv | Group-Object -AsHashTable -AsString -Property Key
```

You can then get values like this:

- PS 2.0: `$($db.4).Data`
- PS 3.0 and higher: `($db.4).Data`

More details: [Turning CSV-Files into "Databases"](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2013/06/12/turning-csv-files-into-quot-databases-quot.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the keys are ascending, without gaps, and start from `1`, then you could go by index (zero based):

```
$desiredKey = 4
$db[$desiredKey-1].data
```

But that seems like a dicey assumption, and the way you're doing it is probably better than that.

You could build a `[hashtable]` and then do direct lookups:

```
$hash = @{}
$db | ForEach-Object { $hash[$_.key] = $_.data }

$db[4]
```

Comment: unfortunately the keys set contains a lot of holes. I'll go with the hash table.